# How can I protect myself from getting hacked in the new version of Google Analytics?

Tags: security, google-analytics, protected, traffic

When I searched up how to keep my Google Analytics website tag safe from being hacked and used by another domain, the answer was always to apply a filter, so that the data you see won't get mixed up.
However, I don't understand, how does that protect other people from seeing your Google Analytics? Because, even if you apply the filter, that just filters the data on your end. But, anybody out there can just find your tag through "View Page Source", create a Google Analytics account data stream with that tag, and bam they can access the data of the tag on your webpage.

Comment: "*How does that protect other people from seeing your Google Analytics?*" I'm not aware of a method one could use to "[see] your Google Analytics" with only the GA identifier included in the page source. Can you provide a reference on this point?

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have found are not to keep your ID safe but to keep your data clean, that is, if in Google Analytics you define the filter based on the host name of your domain, the data you will find in the reports will only be that of yours site (that is, if I copy your code and insert it on my site, the data I send to your Analytics are from my domain, but your filter will block them).

If you also add spam and bot filters, you can keep other fake interactions away. The Property ID however remains explicit on the web page.

However, no one can have access to your data in Analytics via that ID, unless you have given them privileges to their user account.